# SQL How to get data from many datababases?

Tags: sql

I have that query

```
USE database_A /*it will change: database_B, c , d etc..*/

select X.Name1, X.Name2, DB_NAME() AS [Current Database] 
from dbo.table1 A /*it will be the same table*/ 
left join
database_X.dbo.table_X X /*it will be the same database and table*/  on A.ID = X.ID_ID
```

I would like to get a result that shows the values of Name1 and Name2 and the context in which it was made, e.g .:

| Name1 | Name2 | Current Database |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | database_A |
| aaa | ddd | database_A |
| One | Two | database_B |
| One | Two | database_B |
| 222 | 1112 | database_B |
| One | Two | database_c |

Comment: Refer the database explicitly and union all your selects. You may wish to create a dynamic sql from a dbs list.

Comment: ok thanks, but I have a problem because I do not know how to create such  a dynamic sql sql

Comment: You should look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Different products define _database_ in different ways, and also have different functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic sql example

```
-- list of DBs
create table dbs (dbn sysname);

insert dbs
values ('dbnameA'),('dbnameB'),('dbnameC');

-- build the query
declare @q varchar(Max);
select @q = string_agg(s, ' union all ')
from (
   select 'select X.Name1, X.Name2, ''' + dbn + ''' AS [Current Database]' + 
    ' from ' + dbn + '.dbo.table1 A' + 
    ' left join database_X.dbo.table_X X on A.ID = X.ID_ID' s
   from dbs) t

-- check it
select @q;
-- run it
exec (@q);
```